# JSON to Java: How to model lists of objects into generic model

Tags: java, json

I'm making a spreadSheet using SpreadJS, and I should be able to to add, delete and change the value of a key nested inside many objects. Here is how my json is formatted:

```
{
  "version": "10.0.0",
  "sheets": {
    "Sheet1": {
      "name": "Sheet1",
      "data": {
        "dataTable": {
          "0": {
            "0": {
              "value": 129
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "selections": {
        "0": {
          "row": 0,
          "rowCount": 1,
          "col": 0,
          "colCount": 1
        },
        "length": 1
      },
      "theme": "Office",
      "index": 0
    }
  }
}
```

The data represents, say, the value of each cell in the spreadSheet [0,0], [0,1], [1,1] ...etc. I want to parse this data into a List of generic model, for the field dataTable i would like to represent it like this: `Map<Integer, Map<Integer, ValueObj>>` for example in this case `<0, <0, 129>>` but i didn 't find how to do that and how my model would likely be.

I am new to JSON any help is appreciated! Thanks

Comment: Is `ValueObj` a type you have created? Or is it Java's `Object`?

Comment: I didn't create it yet but it can be Integer or String or List of Strings you see ? it depends on the cell's value

Comment: For a start, have a look at Jackson ObjectMapper

Comment: I already started with Jackson ObjectMapper and i create the pojos but i didn't find how the pojo dataTable whould likely be.

Comment: Is there a requirement to identify the *type* of the data (integer, String etc) or are you interested in only the data?

Comment: no, i would like to know the best way to handle this json to be able to change ir for example to add a new value in the row 1, the column 1

Answer (score 0):

Then to handle data, you can have a generic class like :

```
class CellData<T> {
    T data;
}
```

Then read as below :

```
String jsonInput = "{ \"0\": { \"0\": { \"value\": 129 } } }";
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
TypeReference<HashMap<Integer,HashMap<Integer,CellData<Integer>>>> typeRef = 
    new TypeReference<HashMap<Integer, HashMap<Integer, CellData<Integer>>>>() {};
Map<Integer, Map<Integer, CellData<Integer>>> map = mapper.readValue(jsonInput, typeRef);
```

Comment: Can you create all pojos and show me how can you add a value in the row1 column 1 to the json? thanks